# Why does my SwiftUI app date not refresh in background?

Tags: xcode, date, swiftui

Good morning. I have the date at the top of my main view. It displays like this: Thursday, March 16, 2023. My code for it is:

```
  let meetingDate = Date()
  Text(meetingDate.formatted(date: .complete, time: .omitted))
```

The issue is that if the app stays in the background and you swipe up on iPhone and select it the following day, the date has not updated. I have to close the app and reopen it for it to update. I don't understand why.

I haven't tried anything because I don't know what to try. I have searched extensively on the Internet, but have not found a solution. Thank you.

Comment: How are you calculating `meetingDate`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I thought it was pretty clear. When the app is open the date displays correctly. However, if you do not actually close the app, but swipe it away from view so that it is in the background and then Combe back the next day, swipe up from the bottom of the screen where the apps in the background are displayed and select the app, the date has not changed to the current day. You have to then close the app (not swipe away) and reopen it for the date to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically that behaves like that because you set `meetingDate` during initialization only so that's why you have to hard close the app to make `meetingDate` updated.
To fix you problem you can make `meetingDate` as a `@State` property and add listening for your app scene phase changes and update `meetingDate` inside `onChange` handler when `scenePhase` changed to `active`:

```
@Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
@State private var meetingDate: Date = .init()

...

YourView {
  ...
}
.onChange(of: scenePhase) { phase in
    guard phase == .active else {
       return
    }
    meetingDate = Date()
}
```